# Why does print(new_data[0]) only print out the first char of the json file?

Tags: python, json

im trying to print the first object of this json file but it only prints the first char of it.

This is my code:

```
response = requests.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
data = response.json()
new_data = json.dumps(data, indent = 2)
print(str(new_data[0]))
```

result i was hoping for:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    }
```

actual result:

```
[
```

Comment: `json.dumps` encodes a Python object ***to*** JSON. You're printing out the first character of a (JSON) string.

Comment: also the dump is redundant, if you want response in string rather than python dict, use `response.text` instead of `response.json` and then parsing it back to string.

Comment: No need to convert it to a `str`

Comment: The return value of `json.dumps` already is a string. Just `print(new_data)`. If you only want the first entry of data, you should try `new_data = json.dumps(data[0], indent=2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json.dump the first element of the response:

```
import json

response = requests.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
data = response.json()
first_elem = json.dumps(data[0], indent=2)
print(first_elem)
```

Comment: thanks this worked. it also works if i just leave out "json.dumps(data), indent=2" and use "print(data[0])". question: is there a way to indent it without using "json.dumps"?

Comment: @doostaay you could try `pprint` or `pretify`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91810/is-there-a-pretty-printer-for-python-data

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `response.json()` already is a dictionary.

So if you try `first_element = data[0]` you would get what you are looking for.

And then, if you want to make it pretty :

`json.dumps(first_element, indent = 2)`

If you wish a JSON object to behave like a dictionary , take a look at

`json.loads`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Also :
[What's the best way to parse a JSON response from the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877422/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-a-json-response-from-the-requests-library)

Comment: Even if the response is a failure ? (I'm going to check the docs)

Answer (score -1):

json.dumps results in a string.

You are printing the first word of the string by doing `[0]`

For the output that you want, do:

`print(new_data)`